# If $f(x,y)$ is continuous, is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ continuous about $x$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x, y):\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function,  differentiable wrt $y$.

Is $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y}$ continuous wrt $x$?

Comment: Seems that we should look for an example where the difference quotients $\frac{1}{h}(f(x,y_0+h)-f(x,y_0))$ converge but not uniformly in $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} x \sin(y/x), & x \ne 0 \\
0, & x = 0. \end{cases}$$
It is an exercise to check that $f$ is (jointly) continuous everywhere.

It is also clear that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable in $y$ for each fixed $x$, and 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} \cos(y/x), & x \ne 0 \\
0, & x = 0. \end{cases}$$
In particular $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0) = 1$ for all $x \ne 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$, so that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is not continuous in $x$.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not. Try the following:
$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} y\sin(\frac{1}{x}),&x\neq 0\\ 0, &x=0\end{array}\right.$$
Here $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is discontinuous at $x=0$

Comment: Your function $f$ is not continuous !

Comment: It is continuous in $(0,0)$, but your right, it is not globally continuous. I wonder if you can can find such an example...

Comment: I am confused. Because $x_n=\frac{1}{\frac\pi2+n\pi}$ tend to $0$ so (if $f$ is continuous ) $f(x_n,y)$ must tend to $f(0,y)$. but it is divergent.

Comment: I think the statement is true.

Comment: @ C.F.G. This $f$ only works for the point $(0,0)$. In this point $f$ is continuous, because every sequence $(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow (0,0) $satisfies $y_n\sin\frac{1}{x_n}\rightarrow 0$, since $|\sin|\leq 1$.